# How to save a webRTC stream into a file on server with nodejs?

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I get my stream from my client like this :

```
  webrtc_connection.ontrack = async (e) => {
    
 //TODO : RECORD

  }
```

How can I record / save it into a file on server? Apparently nodejs does not have `MediaRecorder`, so I am at loss for going further.

Comment: What is it that you want to record, audio or video?

Comment: @RahulSharma stream includes audio and video

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two options. The first is to use MediaRecorder+Socket.io+FFmpeg. [Here](https://github.com/fbsamples/Canvas-Streaming-Example) is an example of how to stream from the browser to RTMP via node.js, but instead of streaming, you can just save it to the file.

1. draw your video on canvas, use [canvas.captureStream()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/captureStream) to get MediaStream from the canvas;
2. append your audio to MediaStream that you got in the previous step using MediaStream.addTrack();
3. use MediaRecorder to get raw data from the MediaStream;
4. send this raw data via WebSockets to node.js;
5. use FFmpeg to decode and save your video data to a file.

The Second is to use [node-webrtc](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc). You can join your WebRTC room from the server as another participant using WebRTC and record media tracks using FFmpeg. [Here is an example.](https://github.com/node-webrtc/node-webrtc-examples/tree/master/examples/record-audio-video-stream)